# Living in a van: AC vs DC - Invert vs Boost

Tags: electrical

I’m currently upgrading my van, which is my home, and asked myself why am I using a DC-AC Inverter when all of my appliances can run on DC, albeit some would need DC Boosters, but still, is that a more efficient way of approaching it, or do I scratch that idea and stick with an Inverter?

I’m not an electrician, have zero experience, just read a lot, but don’t want to be chasing fools gold based on some limited research.

Comment: Hello and welcome! This question is very broad. Please take a look at the [topic guidance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and consider [editing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/607456/edit) your question to ask something specific.

Comment: The question is too broad. But in my opinion, it is a lot more convenient and cheaper to run everything on AC and focus on finding an efficient inverter. If you go the DC only route, you will have to find exotic products and oddball DC-DC power converters to run them. This will add expense and negate some of the benefits of going all DC in the first place. There is no reason to assume a DC-DC converter is more efficient than an AC-DC converter, for example, although it is one less conversion step which is good.

Comment: If you list the specific appliances that cannot easily run on DC, and their requirements, you will get more useful answers.   You can easily buy 12V dildo adaptors that will power all your USB devices and most new laptops (Using USB-C and PD, I've seen 45W car chargers.  Don't use a 90W laptop in your van.).   What are the one or two things that can't run on 12V *and that also* will not drain a van battery in a few hours?

Comment: You can easily find 12V to 19V DC adaptors, to run a laptop off 12V.

Answer (score 3):

Stick with systems that run on 12V directly. This will be more efficient than stepping up 12V with an inverter. And be realistic: if you need 120V that badly, it’s not #vanlife.

If anything, for convenience you could add a shore power hookup for those rare occasions when you need 120V. But it seems like you’re doing just fine.

Think about it. What things really need AC, in a *van*? Pretty much nothing that’s feasible to run on a battery. On the other hand, basic battery-friendly creature comforts like a propane heater or fridge can be had in 12V, as well as lighting. (You know that, I’m mentioning it for others reading this.)

As far as needing AC, that leaves appliances. Higher power stuff like a microwave oven, blender or a big flatscreen TV? That’s more than a van-sized battery can handle, even with an inverter, which places them in shore-power or generator territory.

And once you cross that Rubicon… you’re out of #vanlife… and into #rvlife.

Now, low-power AC stuff, like laptop chargers? Yes, that can justify an inverter. Yet even that can be worked around and adapted to 12V. USB chargers? No brainer, run those on 12V via adaptors. Satellite dish? Get thee to the KOA…

Anecdotal example. Our pop-up has one 70Ah 12V AGM battery, a rooftop solar panel, and can accept shore power. Shore power, when connected, tops the battery, runs the dual-voltage fridge and powers a couple of convenience outlets. Otherwise the battery is charged by solar or by the truck when it’s running.

In the six years and hundreds of days on the road with our setup, I can think of needing 120V shore power two times, each time to power a laptop brick to be ‘zoom town rats’. I eventually bought a small, 400W inverter to do that rather than use shore power. It’s noisy, I hate it, but it worked.

[image]

**What a Zoom Town Rat may look like *(photo credit: author)***

And since then both our laptops have been replaced with USB-C types, and I have a 12V USB-C adapter. So that doesn’t matter anymore.

MORE INFO:

The specific type of fridge in our camper is an Isotherm (now Dometic) that uses a Danfoss 12V/110V compressor. That allows it to run without an inverter. More about these here: https://www.truckcamperadventure.com/the-danfoss-compessor-refrigerator-pros-cons-and-a-few-tips/

Answer (score 1):

I agree with hacktastical.  Provisionally.

I don't think there's any such thing as an "efficient" inverter.  Any way you slice it, you are forced to allocate a significant part of your battery to *merely the vampire load of having the inverter spun up all the time*.  And if there's anything conservation has taught us, it's that a small load *is a big load* when it runs 24x7.   In my old house, the Comcast cat-warmer took more energy *than, our, dryer*.

So yes. Any inverter you consider - look at its 24x7 vampire load and determine how much battery you'll need to rack to run it, and where that energy will come from.  You only have so much solar panel space.

That does not mean all DC devices are free. A common gas-station USB charger might be quite the little hog, since it's designed for gasoline cars with unlimited energy.

Sometimes you just need AC.  In that case, run the inverter only when it is needed.  For example, refrigerator selection is much better for AC than DC. For a refrigerator, you could have a supervisory system like an Arduino start the inverter at the top of every hour, and monitor AC current inductively.  Current will be around 1A while the refrigerator is running.  When it drops very low for more than 10 seconds, shut the inverter off.

Comment: Modern refrigerators are very efficient because they have long run times. If you put a refrigerator on an inverter you need to let it run all day. Or at least for many hours each day (like 12 or more). The refrigerator is actually the best argument in favor of running your inverter all the time.

Comment: The Victron Phoenix 1200 watt inverter uses 10 Watts when on. That is 240 Wh per day. 20 Amp hours (at 12 V). So if you have 50 or 100 amp hours, then sure, that is too much. But it has an ECO mode where it periodically checks for load. In that mode it only uses 3 Watts. So that is 72 Wh per day. Or 6 Amp hours at 12 Volts. Maybe that is not so bad. And if you need less than 1200 Watts, their smaller inverters use even less power standing by.

Comment: Laptop power supplies are generally very efficient. And inverters are in the low/mid 90's for efficiency.

Comment: Hopefully a cat warmer is a set top box (of which I have zero) and not a modem?

Comment: @jay613 The typical (at least used to be) Comcast modem/router/WiFi box is an ugly, power-hungry beast. And they don't care. After all, if you're paying $'x' per month to rent the thing, are you really looking at how much power it uses? In their defense, Comcast (at least in Maryland) has been pretty good in the last several years about letting you bring your own device, which you can then choose based on price vs. power vs. features. Except (at least as of a few years ago) they wouldn't let you even *pay* to have a static IP unless you used (and rented) their box. Don't get me started...

Comment: @manassehkatz That works for internet, but the problem is if you want TV. First you need their box to decrypt the channels. Second they deliberately won't let you get near TV without it, because the box is pure up-sell into their spectrum of products from cell phone to smart-home and security. They won't even let you remove channels you don't have from the channel guide, so every browse is an upsell. Oh! Video games... one of their upsell products is gaming, so it's also a game console, with high-end VPU hardware and current draw to match.  Also I think it mines bitcoin while you sleep :)

Comment: @mkeith that may be true for 12V fridges. My 120V fridge is near my office, and I hear it cycle on/off and have given it the full Kill-a-Watt treatment. It runs ~1/3 of the time, pulls ~110W when running, and totals about 900Wh/day.  It would be happy as a clam on an hourly schedule.  The Victron's 240Wh means 720Wh of deep cycle lead-acid at safe 66% DoD, which means racking almost a whole 'nother golf cart battery just for its vampire load. And it's only a 1200VA unit that might not even start my fridge.  A proper commitment to AC means more battery and yeah, now it's RV-life.

Comment: My home refrigerator also uses about 1 kWh per day, so I believe you. Anyone buying batteries now should definitely be buying LFP. It is crazy to buy lead batteries now. But I realize some people may have legacy lead installations. Pretty sure the victron will start a refrigerator. I will eventually try it on my refrigerator. The victron has ECO mode which is very similar to the arrangement you suggested where it wakes up periodically to check the load. If it sees a load it stays on. Size of load and frequency of checking are programmable.

Comment: @mkeith ha, they're way ahead of me then.  I'd love to know if it works, we occasionally have outages here and I'd like to get the fridge on backup. Completely agree on the death of lead-acid, the poor repairability of modern cars (and nosedive in resale due to comfort tech going obsolete so fast) guarantees an endless stream of lithium batteries from EVs that were totaled.